# Can't import geopandas (Python 3.7 64 bit)

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to import geopandas in my script but I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/Scripts/Project1/folium_map/89. geographical chart 4.py", line 1, in <module>
    import geopandas
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 12, in <module>
    from geopandas.base import GeoPandasBase, _series_unary_op, _CoordinateIndexer
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from rtree.core import RTreeError
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rtree\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .index import Rtree
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rtree\index.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rtree\core.py", line 133, in <module>
    rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 369, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'Error_GetLastErrorNum' not found
```

My code looks just like this:

```
import geopandas
```

Has anyone else received this error before? And if so, how did they fix it? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 05/02/19:

Also I have GDAL 2.3.3 amd64 installed.

Comment: Which version of GDAL do you use?

Comment: GDAL 2.3.3 amd64

Comment: Did you install `geopandas` with pip? Installation ran without problem?

Comment: Yep I installed it with pip with no problem.

Comment: if you want to use geopandas on windows, `conda` really is the best path forward

Answer (score 1):

Install libspatialindex fixed it for me (I installed geopandas with pip).
You can try the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge libspatialindex=1.9.3
```

If you install geopandas from conda directly, I think it should run without problem.

Comment: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37` OP is not using a conda based python installation